# How to write vb code in classic asp page

Tags: vb.net, asp-classic

I have  this piece of code below which I want to write in classic asp page.

```
    Dim userID, encryptedUsedID, decryptedUsedID As String
    encryptedUsedID = dllname.Encrypt(userID)
    decryptedUsedID = dllname.Decrypt(encryptedUsedID)
```

I am unable to find a way to write this code on a classic asp page.Any suggestion?

Comment: You can't directly call .NET dll in classic asp. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456908/calling-asp-net-from-classic-asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved by the following code:

```
Set Obj = Server.CreateObject("dllname")
UserID=Obj.DecryptForASP(encryptedUserID)
```